# Join tables on varying condition for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

So I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`PRIMARY_DT` date, `CUST_ID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    (`PRIMARY_DT`, `CUST_ID`)
VALUES
    ('2012-03-02', 878 ),
    ('2012-07-02', 456 ),
    ('2012-09-02', 789 )
;


CREATE TABLE table2
    (`dt` date, `CUST_ID` int, `value` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table2
    (`dt`, `CUST_ID`, `value`)
VALUES
    ('2012-03-8', 878, 1)
;
```

I need to add the value from table2 to table1 if a condition is met (date in table 2 is within 7 days of date in table 1). If that isn't the case, then just add value of -9999. So something like this:

| PRIMARY_DT | CUST_ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2012-03-02' | 878 | 1 |
| '2012-03-02' | 456 | -9999 |
| '2012-03-02' | 789 | -9999 |

So far, I can join if the condition is met with the following code:

```
SELECT t1.PRIMARY_DT,
      t1.CUST_ID,
      t2.value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
WHERE t2.value =  (SELECT MIN(tt2.value)
                    FROM table2 tt2
                    WHERE tt2.dt BETWEEN t1.PRIMARY_DT AND t1.PRIMARY_DT+7)
```

I tried adding the -9999 for the cases where there is no match but I'm having tunnel vision. The below gives the same result as above:

```
SELECT t1.PRIMARY_DT,
      t1.CUST_ID,
      t2.value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
WHERE t2.value = (CASE WHEN
                   (SELECT MIN(tt2.value)
                    FROM table2 tt2
                    WHERE tt2.dt BETWEEN t1.PRIMARY_DT AND t1.PRIMARY_DT+7) IS NULL THEN
                   -9999 ELSE (SELECT MIN(tt2.value)
                    FROM table2 tt2
                    WHERE tt2.dt BETWEEN t1.PRIMARY_DT AND t1.PRIMARY_DT+7) END)
```

Either query only gives me:

| PRIMARY_DT | CUST_ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2012-03-02' | 878 | 1 |

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10284fe/6 here is a SQLFiddle with the same information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can largely simplify your solution by

- using a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables
- apply the date condition inside one `CASE` statement

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(t2.dt, t1.PRIMARY_DT) < 7 
            THEN t2.value 
            ELSE -9999 
       END AS value
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q98RDUqzPEYHTLCcYrnf9P/1).

Answer (score 0):

So my tunnel vision is gone after posting this, here is the answer:

```
SELECT t1.PRIMARY_DT,
       t1.CUST_ID,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT MIN(tt2.value)
                    FROM table2 tt2
                    WHERE tt2.dt BETWEEN t1.PRIMARY_DT AND t1.PRIMARY_DT+7) IS NULL
            THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT MIN(tt2.value)
                    FROM table2 tt2
                    WHERE tt2.dt BETWEEN t1.PRIMARY_DT AND t1.PRIMARY_DT+7) END
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CUST_ID = t2.CUST_ID
```